# How do I compile fortan code on a cluster using a given build file

Tags: bash, build, compilation, fortran

I want to run a Fortran code on a cluster. This is to run a test case where all the needed files for the test case are provided.

I have uploaded all the files in a directory on the cluster. Among the files is a "build" file (the content of which is below) that seems to compile the code I want with specific flags using an Intel compiler. I don't know what file type it is (pop os sees it as an audio file which is not very helpful) and I don't know what bash command to use to make it compile the Fortran code.

I have tried `build myfortrancode.f90` and `make build` but I get `command not found` for *build* and `nothing to be done` for *build* using `make` (and I guess it makes sense since there are no "make" files.) I have also checked the `.pbs` file that comes with the test case but as expected it doesn't refer to this build file.

```
ifort -O2 -r8 -fpe0 -g -traceback -c myFortranCode.f90

ifort -O2 -r8 -fpe0 -g -traceback -o myFortranCode myFortranCode.o

rm -f *.mod *.o
```

Comment: It looks like just a list of commands you are meant to type (or source).  Does it seem to fit what you'd expect with the files you have?

Answer (score 1):

Try the bash command below to run all commands in your "build" file.

```
source build
```

Or you can add execute permissions to build and run it with the following bash commands:

```
chmod 775 build
./build
```